# scp to remote host without executing bash_profile file on that host

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, bash

I have a host machine whose **`.bash_profile`** file has some user prompts (bash read command), after reading some input from user it executes some command based on input. This works perfectly fine.

Now when I try to **`scp`** something to this host, it executes **`.bash_profile`** (since scp first ssh into remote host) and it prompts user input and **`scp`** fails. 
What I want is to skip executing **`.bash_profile`** when someone tries to **`scp`** to this host (personally I do not think this is possible) or know someone is trying to **`scp`** in **`.bash_profile`** (somehow catch it in **`.bash_profile`**) and skip some commands accordingly.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to this in [an answer to a similar question over on the Unix site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18647/19434). Put this line at the top of your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return
```

Comment: Also of possible interest may be [Mark Hudson's thoughts on restricting output to `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116934/19434). My `.bashrc` file sources `.bash_profile`, so I may have been unwittingly shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: this worked like a charm on a red hat fedora that was giving us that issue, never needed such thing for ubuntu servers though. Thank you!